# Trying to copy from XP NTFS file system to 7 NTFS file system

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

Recently I've installed Windows 7. I was used to use XP before. While trying to copy Firefox profile from XP's NTFS drive (`D:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Application Data\Mozilla`) to 7's NTFS drive (`C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla`), Windows 7 tells that I need to provide administrator permission to copy those files. My Windows 7 account already has admin permissions, as this is the only account (am I correct?). But still I cannot copy. How can I copy files from old system drive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an illustrated tutorial:

**[How to Take Ownership & Grant Permissions to Access Files & Folder in Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm)**

if you frequently have to 'take ownership', i recommend to add this feature to your context menu:

**[Add Take Ownership Option in Right Click Context Menu of Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2173/add-take-ownership-option-in-right-click-context-menu-of-windows-7.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

With UAC active, even if logged as an "administrator", you need to give administrator privileges to programs who write in "sensitive" places. This is because UAC does such a good job of protecting you from yourself, that your effective permissions are lower than your maximal ones.

What you need to do is right click on the program that does the copy, and click "Run as Administrator" (yes, even though you're logged-in as such!). Alternatively, you can turn UAC totally off (if you have other equivalent protection).

Comment: sorry, but turning UAC off will do nothing for you if you do not have ownership and/or access permission

Comment: @Molly: you're right, but that's not the message. I'm trying to explain why being administrator is not enough to avoid these messages.

Comment: @Molly: Anyway, I'm not sure that his problem IS ownership.

Comment: Yes, my problem was related to ownership. It is resolved now thanks to Molly.